# Zend framework from Mac Server: Fatal Error class not found?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I've set up a php server on my Mac in the Webserver folder. Everything seems to be working but when I set up classes and view page in DW I receive this error:

```
 "Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Date' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/practice/practice/_includes/DateUtility.php on line 6:"
```

and this:

```
"Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Date.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/practice/practice/_includes/DateUtility.php on line 2"
```

I've seen some threads about altering the php.ini file and making sure the path is correct to _includes, but there is no php.ini file in the apache2 folder.

Is there another file I can configure to correct the file path to the Zend library?

The framework is placed in the Documents folder on the web server now.
Sorry if this sounds totally newbie, but yes I'm a newbie.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try creating a file in your public directory with only this line:  phpinfo();die; to see where the php.ini is located in your system and then look for the path var.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. File was an a / etc folder. Would have never found it. Now to try and configure for Zend . Be well